# How to keep single Info window open at the same time in Google map V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

aI know that this one is repeated question,

I am using google map v3 on my Django web based applicaiton. Where i am using `Markers, Infowindow and polyline`. Everything works fine, except the one when i click on a marker to show the content by Info window, the previous opened info window didn't closed.

I am posting the my map code(only the script part or which are the useful):

```
var marker = add_marker(flightPlanCoordinates[i][0], flightPlanCoordinates[i][1],"Event Detail",myHtml);
```

Here `myHtml` is a variable which contains the Info window content. I didn't define the variable here. SO ignore it.

```
    marker.setMap(map);
    }

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                 path: flightPlanCoordinatesSet,
                 strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                 strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                 strokeWeight: 2
                  });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
}

function add_marker(lat,lng,title,box_html) {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: box_html
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      map: map,
      title: title
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,this);
});   

return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of multiple infoWindows use only one instance.

When clicking on a marker, first close the infoWindow, then set the new content and open the infoWindow.

```
function add_marker(lat,lng,title,box_html) 
{
  //create the global instance of infoWindow 
  if(!window.infowindow)
  {
    window.infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  } 

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      map: map,
      title: title
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.setContent(box_html);
    infowindow.open(map,this)
  });   

  return marker;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying , I tried with this option. but didn't work.May be i was wrong would it be possible for you to show me pseudo code for add listener method

Comment: @Dr.Molle I have multiple marker in `LatLngBounds` if I create the global instance of infoWindow the last infowinodow shows all the pointer

Comment: @Blue Bells: can you post a link to the page?