# How can I close an infowindow with the Google Maps API when clicking the something else marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want that infowindow to close, when I click somewhere else in the map or something else marker. I.e., only one infowindow is open at the same time and all other infowindows are closed.

But how can I do it?

My code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

addMarker({
  coords: { lat: 62.791711, lng: 22.808479 },
  content: 'test 1'
});
addMarker({
  coords: { lat: 65.799962, lng: 24.497773 },
  content: 'test 2'
});
addMarker({
  coords: { lat: 62.331629, lng: 22.890667 },
  content: 'test 3'
});

function addMarker(props) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: props.coords,
    map: map
  });

  if (props.content) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: props.content
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428017/how-to-keep-single-info-window-open-at-the-same-time-in-google-map-v3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To only have one info window open at a time, create a global variable that will hold a single InfoWindow instance.

```
var infoWindow;
```

Then, in your initialization function (`initMap`), instantiate the info window:

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Change your `addMarker` function to the following:

```
function addMarker(props) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: props.coords,
    map: map
  });

  if (props.content) {
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(props.content);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
}
```

And if you want to close the info window when the user clicks on the map, you can add this event listener to the map:

```
map.addListener('click', function() {
    if (infoWindow) infoWindow.close();
});
```

Here is [a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sucedun/1/edit?js,output) with a working example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! These solved my problem!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable for infoWindow and check if it is already open assigned. If this is true then close and open another one:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
var actInfoWindow;

addMarker({
    coords:{lat:62.791711, lng:22.808479},
    content:'test 1'
});
addMarker({coords:{lat:65.799962, lng:24.497773},
     content:'test 2'
}),
    addMarker({coords:{lat:62.331629, lng:22.890667},
    content:'test 3'
});

function addMarker(props){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:props.coords,
        map:map,
    });

    if(props.content){
        actInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:props.content,
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function(){
        var tempMap = actInfoWindow.getMap();
        if (tempMap !== null && typeof tempMap !== "undefined") {
          actInfoWindow.close();
        }
        actInfoWindow = infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
```